# Animating a circular border using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="icon">
  <div class="iconBorder">
    <div class="iconContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
steps = 1
loops = 100 / steps
increment = 360 / loops
half = loops / 2

percentage = 35

if (percentage < half) {
  nextdeg = 90 + (increment * percentage)
  $('.icon .iconBorder').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(90deg, #263238 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(' + nextdeg + 'deg, white 50%, #263238 50%, #263238)')
} else {
  nextdeg = -90 + (increment * (percentage - half))
  $('.icon .iconBorder').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(' + nextdeg + 'deg, white 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, white 50%, #263238 50%, #263238)')
}
```

I have the code above and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PavSidhu/Lqfbv6p3/) which creates a border around a circular icon depending on the value of `percentage` which varies. I would like to animate the border around the icon so that it appears to start at 0% (0˚) and then move to the percentage supplied, in this case 65% (126˚).

I also want the animate to ease in and out. I'm not sure how I would achieve this since I could not simply use a CSS transition as I'm using a CSS hack to create the border using a gradient background in the first place. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need JS to do that? CSS also can handle it

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal could you please provide a CSS solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807610/css-only-animate-draw-circle-with-border-radius-and-transparent-background

Comment: http://codepen.io/katmai7/pen/jCAhv