# Partially fill object when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for a content cycle I have created with the help from some other Stack Overflow users. Is it possible to have the circular arrow fill up partially depending on what box your hovered on. Example: If the user hovers on box four (the bottom box) the circular arrow would fill up with a different color only up until that box. Is this possible to do with pure CSS only? If not would this be possible with vanilla JavaScript (no Jquery)? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.container .row {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.one:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.two {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.two:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.three {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.three:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.four {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.four:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}


.five {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.five:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.six {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.six:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 130px;
  height: 65px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -10px;
  left: 55px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="six"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Just my first thoughts: Surely possible with SVG. Probably possible with CSS via `clip-path`, but browser support might be (too) limited. Maybe possible with CSS in another way (I've seen people create color circles with it), but couldn't say how.

Comment: I would try a combination of [radial CSS gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients) and CSS transitions.  I'm not sure that you would be able to accomplish this entirely without JS.

Comment: Some time ago I posted an example of a CSS animation that covered all the circle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866340/1926369  In this case, you only need to have the precalculated case covering 1/6th of the circle way up to 5/6th.   I will try to give you a more detailed answer

Comment: @vals yeah something similar to that, and alright, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fully changed your layout.

Now everything works ok. And also, making changes in the position will be easier.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

.ele, .arrow, .circle {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   margin: auto;
}

#one {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(0deg);
}
#two {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-60deg);
}
#three {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-120deg);
}
#four {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-180deg);
}
#five {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-240deg);
}
#six {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-130px) rotate(-300deg);
}


.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.ele:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:scale(1.019);
  border-color:f4f4f4;
  background-color:#214d84;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px #888888;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;
  left: -17px;
}

#two:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: red;
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}
#three:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: red;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#four:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
#five:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  transform: rotate(26deg);
}
#six:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-top-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}
#one:hover ~ .arrow {
  border-color: red;
}
#one:hover ~ .circle:after {
  border-top-color: red;
}


.circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -96px;
  left: -36px;
  background: #fff;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  top: -83px;
  left: -44px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="ele" id="one">1</div>
    <div class="ele" id="two">2</div>
    <div class="ele" id="three">3</div>
    <div class="ele" id="four">4</div>
    <div class="ele" id="five">5</div>
    <div class="ele" id="six">6</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet work! But it seems like the pointer event is list when overing on the blue boxes that lie inside of the area delineated by the arrow?

Comment: @vals possible to have the draw effect like in your example you commented earlier?

Comment: @Terry I had already said that the hover wasn't working. But to make it work ok a full rewrite of the layout was necessary

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Yes, adapting my anterior answer here would be possible. But I think that I have already answered this question, and you should post another question for this new request

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using **images** for your arrow, you could have a different image for the arrow depending on which box is hovered and then you can change the image out via css:

```
.one:hover {
  background: url("box1arrow.jpg"); // obviously, set this to whichever image you need
}
```

Comment: Mmm I thought about that, I think I would use that as a last resort if I cant get it to work. Thanks for the reply!