# Create an animatable radial mask for layered images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have two circular SVG images stacked on top of each other. The top image is grayscale. The bottom image is full-color.

What I'd like to do is, via a 1-100 percentage, remove the top image like the hands sweeping the face of a clock based on number. Let's say I'm at 25%. From 12 o'clock to 3 o'clock the grayscale image would be gone like a pie wedge) revealing the identical full-color image below. (see image for more clarity).

[example of radial mask concept](http://ntrc8.us/1KeWKts)

Is this possible to do with HTML5/CSS? JQuery? Some way else I'm not considering?

Comment: This could be modified to get what you want: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/32Y8U/181/). Got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385924/css-animate-circle-border-filling-with-color).

Comment: I was working on a solution for this using clip masks and arcs. But, my solution is dependent on the SVG markup (which may not make a good answer)...

Comment: This might be what you are looking for!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385924/css-animate-circle-border-filling-with-color

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle of what i came up with http://jsfiddle.net/3a5eubcv/ .Basically your background image would be the red circle and then you have 2 masks floating over it (divs with semitransparent background). Sorry for not adding the javascript for it as well, but for you 25%  = `transform:rotate(90deg);`.When you reach 50%, the right mask should stop and the left one should continue. 75% = `.circle-mask-right{transform:rotate(180deg); .circle-mask-left{transform:rotate(90deg);}` .I'm sure the code can be simplified, but hopefully this could get you going.